# Reading a Contact List from Office 365/Exchange using Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have read several StackOverflow questions (more than 2 years old) regarding the ability to read/write a contact list from a user's contact folder(s), and it appears that it is not supported. I believe I have confirmed this with my own testing.  A response to

```
GET "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user@domain.com/contactfolders/{folderid}\contacts
```

will produce a list of individual contacts, but contact lists are ignored. (Interestingly, if I include the option "count=true" I will get a @odata.count value indicating the presence of my lists, but no actual data).  I was hoping the beta endpoint would correct this deficiency but no joy that I can tell.  Is there indeed no way to obtain or create a contact list using Graph? (I know I can do it using EWS). I have not yet tried the Groups API but from what I can this is something entirely different.

Comment: I suggest that you and any future person who finds this post should request this feature at [Microsoft Graph User Voice](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests).